# How to convert a monochrome image to 2d array in ruby

Tags: ruby, image-processing, rmagick, monochrome

[digit 5 monochrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86vDy.gif)

How to convert the sample monochrome image to 2d array in ruby.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I had tried do it use pycall plugin. However, I had to import again manual when execute in rails console. Pycall not work sometimes.

```
require 'pycall'
require 'pycall/import'
include PyCall::Import

pyimport 'numpy', as: :np
pyimport 'PIL.Image', as: :pil_image

image = pil_image.open.(image_path).convert.('1')
img = np.asarray.(image, dtype: np.uint8)
list = img.tolist.().map { |l| l.to_a }
```

Comment: Please share the code you've tried. What specifically are you having trouble with? See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMagick offers a couple of solutions. Use [get_pixels](https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#get_pixels) to get an array of [Pixel](https://rmagick.github.io/struct.html#Pixel) objects. Pixel objects are structures from which you can get the values of the red, green, and blue channel. Because the image is monochrome the channel values will either be 0 or [QuantumRange](https://rmagick.github.io/constants.html). Scale the values by QuantumRange to force them to either 0 or 1.

Alternatively, use [export_pixels](https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#export_pixels). Again, scale the returned values by QuantumRange to get either 0 or 1.

In either case you can minimize the storage requirements (if your image is large) by operating on successive subsets (a single row, for example) of the image.